# Prestashop Error: I am using Prestashop 8.0.4, when I am clicking on Modules, It should redirect me to it's UI, instead it is redirect me to the store

Tags: php, plugins, prestashop

[Modules Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaW8M.png)

[Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31RYH.jpg)

I installed Prestashop 8.0.4, when I am clicking on modules tab it is redirecting me to the store, instead it has to redirect me to modules UI.I have been trying for a week now , could not find the solution, any help would be appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.